# Break up an {{# each}} block every N items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I'm working in a meteor project that needs to display a grid of users as shown here:

[image: grid Layout]

In Django was easy, I would use the list counter and get its modulo, and if the module was 0, then I would close the `row div` tag and add a new `row div` tag.

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:'2' %}
  </div>
  <div class="row">
{% endif %}
```

But when I try to do this in a Meteor template:

```
Template.available_user_list.helpers({
  users: function () {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  },
  count: ()=>{
    return Meteor.users.find().count();
  },
  isModulo: function (dividend, divisor) {
    return dividend % divisor == 0;
  }
});
```

*html*

```
<!-- display a list of users -->
<template name="available_user_list">
  <h2>Choose someone to chat with:</h2>
  <div class="row">
    {{#each users}}
      {{> available_user}}
      {{#if isModulo count 4 }}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I get the following error:

> => Errors prevented startup:
>          While processing files with templating (for target web.browser):
>          client/templates/lobby_page.html:14: Unexpected HTML close tag
>          ...                                if isModule tags.

I can't use the pattern as Django. How can I insert a new row every *N* items?

Comment: The problem is in `</div><div class="row">`, the elements should be closed. The tags do not matches.

Comment: Yeah, i know it but i need do some like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Meteor, but the pattern I would use is to split the array into "chunks" of the size you want, then loop over each chunk for the divs, then loop over each chunks users:

```
Template.available_user_list.helpers({
  users: function () {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  },
  count: ()=>{
    return Meteor.users.find().count();
  },
  chunks: function(chunkSize) {
      var R = [];
      var users = Meteor.users.find();
      for (var i=0,len=users.count(); i<len; i+=chunkSize)
          R.push(users.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
          return R;
  }
});

<!-- display a list of users -->
<template name="available_user_list">
  <h2>Choose someone to chat with:</h2>
  {{#each chunk 4}}
      <div class="row">
          {{#each .}}
              {{> available_user}}
          {{/each}}
      </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use index for this. Check if current doc index/counter is divided by your . So you code will be something like this.

```
<template name="available_user_list">
  <h2>Choose someone to chat with:</h2>
  <div class="row">
    {{#each users}}
      {{> available_user}}
      {{#if isModulo @index 4}}
        {{{innerDivs}}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.available_user_list.helpers({
  users: function () {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  },
  isModulo: function (dividend, divisor) {
    ++dividend;
    return dividend % divisor == 0;
  },
 innerDivs: function(){
         return '</div><div class="row">';
 }
});
```

So Basically you just have to put @ in front of count and increase the count value before divide because its initialize with 0 first time. Don't need to define any count/index from helper.
I hope that all make you sense.

Comment: Yeah but, put the `div` tags in these way break my meteor app.

Comment: I have updated my answer this may solve your problem.